# Altera design library does not contain primary unit

Tags: shared-libraries, fpga, intel-fpga, quartus

I am using following altera 2008 library:

```
library altera_2008;
use altera_2008.fixed_generic_pkg.all;
```

When running the Quartus 17.1 compiler I get following error message:

```
Error (10481): VHDL Use Clause error at Polyfit.vhd(48): design library "altera_2008" does not contain primary unit "fixed_generic_pkg". Verify that    the primary unit exists in the library and has been successfully compiled.
```

The Quartus libraries are in following standard folder:

```
 quartus\libraries\vhdl\ieee\2008
```

**Question:**
Why do I get such error message when using the standard Altera libraries and how can I solve it?

Thanks!

Comment: Is this library new in Quartus Prime 17.1? I can't see it in Quartus Prime 17.0. I would like to investigate your problem. Do I need a newer version?

Comment: It seems Altera does not support fixed point. This library is from vhdl.org and not from Altera.

Comment: vhdl.org does not exist anymore. It was shutdown some years ago.